# Why are my dates not properly localized with default_locale?

Tags: cakephp, locale, cakephp-4.x

I cannot figure out why my dates are not converted to FR locale, although I have properly setup the APP_DEFAULT_LOCALE in my app.php file.

I got **Sun, 3 October, 09:00**, but I would like to have **Dim, 3 octobre, 09:00**

Is there something else I need to do ?

```
'App' => [
        'namespace' => 'App',
        'encoding' => env('APP_ENCODING', 'UTF-8'),
        'defaultLocale' => env('APP_DEFAULT_LOCALE', 'fr_FR'),
        'defaultTimezone' => env('APP_DEFAULT_TIMEZONE', 'Europe/Brussels'),
```

Here is how I show the date in my view :

```
<?= h($upcomingEvent->startdate->format('D, j F, H:i')) ?>
```

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That setting does not affect the `format()` method, but the `i18nFormat()` method (and object to string conversion)!

Also be aware that the `i18nFormat()` method does *not* use the standard PHP formatting pattern syntax, but **[the ICU syntax](https://unicode-org.github.io/icu/userguide/format_parse/datetime/#datetime-format-syntax)**:

```php
$upcomingEvent->startdate->i18nFormat('E, d MMMM, HH:mm')
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Date & Time > i18nFormat()](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/core-libraries/time.html#Cake%5CI18n%5CFrozenTime::i18nFormat)**

Comment: Ok, got it. Works now indeed ! Thanks mate, you made my day !